# Custom UIView in UIScrollView drawRect never called

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, drawrect

I have in a controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // Add a scroolView
   self.scroolViewDay.scrollEnabled = YES;
   // Compute the content Size of the TableDays
   self.scroolViewDay.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scroolViewDay.frame.size.width, 
                                               80 * 48); // TO MODIFY!
   [self.scroolViewDay addSubview:self.tableDays];
   [self.tableDays setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The controller has a `XIB` where the `UIScrollView` is into.
The custom view **TableDays** has a custom `drawRect` which is never called:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"sono in drawRect");
}
```

Why?

Comment: The solution is to init the frame.
See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271681/simple-uiview-drawrect-not-being-called?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) setNeedsDisplay {
    [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay)];
    [super setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Add this code, and just override setNeedsDisplay method in your main view and I hope that you know that all of your subviews should be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding it programmatically, add it from the `storyboard` with the correct constraints and see if it getting called.
In my case, there was a problem with the constraints I'm adding to this custom view.

This is the code with the problem,

```
    let header = HeaderBackgroundView(frame: view.bounds)
    scrollView.addSubview(header)

    header.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.leading.equalTo(scrollView.snp.leading)
      make.trailing.equalTo(scrollView.snp.trailing)
      make.top.equalTo(scrollView.snp.top)
      make.height.equalTo(200)
    }
```

i fixed it by adding the center x constraint:

```
    header.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.leading.equalTo(scrollView.snp.leading)
      make.trailing.equalTo(scrollView.snp.trailing)
      make.top.equalTo(scrollView.snp.top)
      make.centerX.equalTo(scrollView.snp.centerX) // this line.
      make.height.equalTo(200)
    }
```